# Pro and cons of using UISpec4J or FEST

Tags: java, swing, unit-testing, automated-tests

We have an application that follows the MVC pattern therefore having a big GUI part to test for.

What I filtered from reading various posts is that the two best options right now are `UISpec4J` and `FEST`.

What are the pro and cons of each option? Is there anything `UISpec4J` can or can't do that the other one can?

Are both built on top of JUnit or are they a framework on its own?

Answer (score 1):

They are both build on JUnit. One of the worst things about UISpec4J is that it's not supported since about 2 years so it doesn't work currently with jre1.7. Especially on the unix base OS where XToolkit use. I think it's enough to use FEST.